# Detecting page change and set url based on that React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have shop component (baseurl/shop) , I have added filters functionality which updates current url based on condition filters change. Now I want to save this url, so that whenvever I come again to this shop component from any other component instead of (baseurl/shop) it should load (baseurl/shop?filters&categ=electronics).
How can I do this do I need middleware or can store url in redux.

App.js

```
 <Route exact path="/shop" component={Shop} />
```

Navheader.js

```
 <Item key="shop" >
               <Link to="/shop">Shop Page</Link>
 </Item>
```